# overwriting react-native stylesheets styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a custom react component that looks like this:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Input, Item } from 'native-base';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { moderateScale, verticalScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { styles as commonStyles } from '~/styles/RegistrationStyles';

type FieldInputProps = {
  handleChange: (e: string) => undefined;
  handleBlur: (e: string) => undefined;
  value: string;
  fieldType: string;
  placeholderText?: string;
  hidePasswordIcon?: string;
  hidePassword?: boolean;
  togglePassword?: () => void;
  icon: string;
};

export const FieldInput: React.FunctionComponent<FieldInputProps> = ({
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  fieldType,
  placeholderText,
  value,
  hidePassword,
  hidePasswordIcon,
  togglePassword,
  icon,
}) => {
  return (
    <Item rounded style={styles.personalListItem}>
      <Icon name={icon} size={moderateScale(20)} color="green" />
      <Input
        autoFocus={true}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        style={{ fontSize: moderateScale(15) }}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={handleChange(fieldType)}
        onBlur={handleBlur(fieldType)}
        value={value}
        secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
      />
      {togglePassword ? (
        <Icon
          name={hidePasswordIcon}
          onPress={togglePassword}
          style={commonStyles.iconStyle}
          size={moderateScale(20)}
          color="green"
        />
      ) : null}
    </Item>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2E3331',
    flex: 1,
  },
  personalListItem: {
    width: moderateScale(320),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderRadius: moderateScale(10),
    height: verticalScale(50),
    paddingRight: moderateScale(20),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(10),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(20),
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontSize: moderateScale(20),
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginVertical: moderateScale(10),
    color: '#17D041',
  },
  subtext: {
    color: '#17D041',
    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
  },
  subtextBold: {
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    color: '#17D041',
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
  },
  button: {
    height: moderateScale(50),
    width: moderateScale(350),
    borderRadius: moderateScale(10),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: moderateScale(5),
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(15),
  },
});
```

Usually when I use this component, I want to keep using this style. However, in one particular case, I want to overwrite the styles. For example, change the width or the background color of the input field etc. However, if I try to overwrite the styles, there are no changes.

```
<FieldInput style={styles.fieldInput}
                      handleChange={handleChange}
                      handleBlur={handleBlur}
                      value={values.phoneNumber}
                      fieldType="phoneNumber"
                      icon="phone"
                      placeholderText="49152901820"
                    />

 fieldInput: {
    width: moderateScale(320),
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `style` prop in your component. Please fix it as shown below.

```
export const FieldInput: React.FunctionComponent<FieldInputProps> = ({
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  fieldType,
  placeholderText,
  value,
  hidePassword,
  hidePasswordIcon,
  togglePassword,
  icon,
  style,
  rounded,
}) => {
  return (
    <Item rounded={rounded} style={[styles.personalListItem, style]}>
      /* remaining code code */
    </Item>
  );
};
```

Comment: Currently my input is "rounded". Is there any way I change it such that it should be rounded only if I pass the rounded attribute? Or can I do something to change rounded to attribute in one particular case?

Comment: Could you please explain what's happening here? In props, I added ```rounded?: boolean;``` and changed the component like you suggested. It works but I don't really get how. I am calling the component like above, and the it's now a line. However, on the other places where I am also using this component, it's still rounded even though I am not passing the rounding keyword. Maybe you can give examples of how to call this component in both cases

Comment: Actually, it should add `rounded` only if you're passing `rounded={true}`. If you don't pass it or pass it false, then it shouldn't be rounded. Maybe `Item` has default styles as rounded and removes it only if you pass `false`. But if you want to achieve this and control the rounded property, then you can pass rounded to `Item` like this `<Item rounded={!!rounded}`. So, even if you don't pass `rounded` to `FieldInput` it'll pass `rounded` as `false` to `Item`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing the styles as a parameter, lets say you want to use it for the outer wrap, you can do it like below

```
 <Item rounded style={[styles.personalListItem,this.props.style]}>
```

If a style prop is received then it will overwrite the one in personalListItem, else it will use the styles in personalListItem.

You will have to add the style to the props, also you can add separate style props for inner components and use them the same way.

If you want to have only the style that is passed you can do this

```
  <Item rounded style={this.props.style||styles.personalListItem}>
```

Which will use the personalListItem if a style prop is not passed

Comment: Currently my input is "rounded". Is there any way I change it such that it should be rounded only if I pass the rounded attribute? Or can I do something to change rounded to attribute in one particular use case?